# Should GUID's be unique?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-provision

I'm a little confused about the guid's used in the provisioning template.
I understand that I can generate a new guid with the {guid} token. What is not clear, when shall I use it? What is the scope of the uniqueness of the guid? Can I have 2 lists in my site collection that have fields with the same guid?

I provision a list, add a field like:

```
<Field Type="LookupMulti" DisplayName="Predecessors" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" List="{listid:Projects}" ShowField="Title" Mult="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE" ID="{guid}" SourceID="{{listid:Projects}}" StaticName="Predecessors" Name="Predecessors" ColName="int2" RowOrdinal="0" Group="" RelationshipDeleteBehavior="None" Version="1" />
```

Works fine, the field is created. I apply the same template again, a new field is created with the same name.

I add a static guid like:

```
<Field Type="LookupMulti" DisplayName="Predecessors" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" List="{listid:Projects}" ShowField="Title" Mult="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="FALSE" ID="{abf43f9e-247c-451c-859a-2eccb26929bb}" SourceID="{{listid:Projects}}" StaticName="Predecessors" Name="Predecessors" ColName="int2" RowOrdinal="0" Group="" RelationshipDeleteBehavior="None" Version="1" />
```

Looks like working, no new field is created when I apply it to the same site, but of course, when I make a new site based on the same template, the field will have the same guid. Will this cause any issues?

Answer (score 0):

Site collections are very isolated 'boxes'. So it's no issue if you reuse a guid for a field in multiple site collections.

For a subsite I'm not sure if it's safe to reuse a guid.